# JAR file, server generator

Tags: java, php, android, server

Is it possible, to generate JAR file with custom package name via server?
What technology? I have access for php/rubby server with direct admin. It's VPS but I don't want to install anything additional.

I like to make service where people can make jar library from my java code with custom package name and download it. I know that android ad networks are using this feature.

Maybe some paid or free solutions exists?

Comment: "What technology?" -- the JDK, specifically the **`javac`** and **`jar`** tools that Java developers use.

Comment: ^^ use. Also you need to know how to make one by passing the right params in addition to making your own manifest.